# Draw a vertical line when clicking on the series in highcharts.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know how to draw vertical line in highcharts. But it's possible only when I click anywhere except upon the series. When I click on the series, no prompt is given. If I click anywhere else in the chart container, then it I get a prompt. Please give me a solution. My attempt so far:

```
$('#save_line_vertical').click(function(event) {

        var label=document.getElementById("line_label_vertical").value;
        if(label!=null)
        {
            var id = 'vertLine' + Math.random();
            chart.addPlotLine({
            value: axis_value,
            color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
            width: 2,
            id: id,
            label : {
            text : label
            },
            events: {
            click: function(e) {
                chart.removePlotLine(id);
                }
            },
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/3AqM7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add click event to series object too, with small polishing, see:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    var label = prompt('Label for Vertical Line');
                    if (label != null) {
                        var chart = this.xAxis;
                        chart.addPlotLine({
                            value: chart.toValue(event.x),
                            color: '#' + (Math.random() * 0xEEEEEE << 0).toString(16),
                            width: 2,
                            id: 'vertLine',
                            zIndex: 9999,
                            label: {
                                text: label
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3AqM7/5/

Comment: thanks.@Pawel can you tell me what I have to change in case of trend line? I mean what if I draw a trendline upon the series.

Comment: I don't know how do you draw trend line, sorry. Just compare with my changes for vertical line and do the same for trend line...

Comment: I just figured it out the somehow this solution is not working in firefox...but its working in chrome. Can you tell me is there any fix for firefox?

Comment: Sure, instead of `event.x`, use `event.chartX`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3AqM7/6/

Comment: Fus : this is how I draw the trendline.http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/7AF6X/1/  But clicking on the series doesn't draw trendline.

Comment: Fus: thanks a lot...previously I didn't noticed the error in console. it was not working because of those errors. I just updated my answer with this http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/7AF6X/2/

Comment: You still have errors in console (j++ is undefined). After removing that I noticed you need to use `this.chart.addSeries` not `this.addSeries`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7AF6X/3/